Positive feedback for Ph.D. students, negative feedback for me
There are many questions on the Academia forum by Ph.D. students, who have run into mental or physical problems. Or who have a dispute with their Ph.D. professors.
Usually these questions are well received. The questions get upvoted. There are nice answers giving useful advice to the OP.
I have once asked a similar question, about my interactions with my Ph.D. professors. It happened 30 years ago, after I had obtained my Ph.D. and when I was unemployed. Instead of helping me find a job, my professors asked me to help them to write a book. Without any payment. Their idea was that by becoming a co-author my chances at the job market would improve. [Needless to say this never materialized.] I asked the question whether my professors' behaviour was ethical.
The reactions to my post were all negative. I was ridiculed for asking a question about something that happened 30 years ago. Why? I got down-voted. And the question was closed. Why?

Are you asking about this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176815/is-it-unethical-to-ask-an-unemployed-academic-to-be-an-unpaid-co-author-of-a-boo ? It has been heavily edited at this point.

Yes. It seems someone wants to restore that post.

First, you seem to have vandalized your question. This is not allowed here, and I have rolled it back. It's impossible to tell how many of the downvotes on your question are responding to the vandalization.
Second, our help center states that you should ask only about "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Given that this situation occurred 30 years ago, and you couldn't articulate a present-tense problem that you were trying to solve, it is not surprising that your question was closed.
Indeed, I wrote three years ago:

what do you want us to tell you? Do you just want to hear us say "yeah, those guys were unethical jerks, they took advantage of you"? Or are you asking us to assess whether they violated professional ethical standards and you could get them in trouble? As it is...[this] is more of a rant than a question.

You never responded, but this is the key question. It is not our role to adjudicate disputes, and particularly not disputes that are 30 years old. But if you could have articulated a present-tense goal (such as getting them fired or getting paid for your work), we could have advised you on that. Since you couldn't specify a present-tense goal, we can only assume that there isn't one. After 30+ years, some old injustices can no longer be corrected but only become moot.
Third, your postscript indicates that you had already contacted the relevant authorities, and the authorities indeed (1) took your complaint seriously and (2) assured you that this sort of thing would never be allowed to happen today. Which is great, it sounds like you've already achieved the best possible present-tense outcome. So there is no "actual problem that you face."

When my post got ridiculed, down voted and closed, I decided to delete it. Now when a post is closed, the OP normally gets the choice between deleting the post or editing it. In my case the delete option was blocked. You can call my behaviour "vandalizing" but that is just a fancy choice of words.

Yes, it is our policy that you cannot delete posts with answers, since that would be unfair to the people who took time to write answers.
